# What is this illustration style?

Tags: illustration, line-art

I notice it's common in sticker art

[image: flower sticker]

It's chararcteristics are solid strokes, contouring lines and solid shading.

It almost, but not quite, looks like newspaper style type ornaments that consist of lines due to electrotyping.

Comment: Thanks @user287001

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a **woodcut** or a vector drawing mimicking one.

Searching for terms like "floral woodcut" or "woodcut flower" gives similar results.

Comment: Ah thank you, yep those terms reveal almost the exact same style. It's gotta be woodcut illustration style